# I'm getting this error, create server with nodejs hapi framework

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

When I hit node index.js command. I am getting this error message:

```
    /var/www/html/local/node/hapi/index.js:11
    throw err;
    ^

    Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL 27.0.0.1:3000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1245:19)
    at listen (net.js:1294:10)
    at net.js:1404:9
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.asyncCallback [as callback] (dns.js:62:16)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:81:10)
```

Comment: Are you sure `27.0.0.1` is the correct address to be listening on?

Comment: I suspect it to be a typo. You should run the application in `127.0.0.1`

Comment: can you please share some code where you created server instance and attempting to start?